# Creating a view (cakePHP noob)

Tags: cakephp

I've been reading until my eyes are swollen, and having troubles finding what should be a simple answer.

I am not new to PHP, but I am new to cakePHP.  Please bear with me, and have patience with my ignorance of lack of knowledge of the terminology.

I have been asked to help make some fixes on a cakePHP developed site, that was recently created.

The site is missing a page for "http://domain.com/logout".  I can see the functions I need to access in the UserController, but I am not sure where to put the .ctp file to generate the view.

Let's just say I want the logout.ctl file to be something as simple as: 
      echo "Hello World";

Under my app/View folder I have the sub-folders Home, & User that I have tried to place this file into.  I am assuming I have to do something else as well, but I have not been able to locate what that is.

Any assistance is appreciated.  Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

1.By default, you should link your view and controller together by creating `Views/Controller/action.ctp`.

Since the url is linked to Controller by routes, views are not associated with it directly.

For example, if you have set

```
Router::connect('/logout/', array('controller' => 'User', 'action' => 'logout'));
```

, then you may want to create Views/User/logout.ctp.

If you have set

```
Router::connect('/logout/', array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'logout'));
```

, then you may want to create Views/Home/logout.ctp.

2.You can change the view in your action with `$this->view='sample'` or `$this->render('sample');` and then create the view file with name `sample.ctp`.

3.You can also read a view of another folder with `$this->render('/Sample/logout');`.
Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

4.If you use themes `$this->theme = 'Example';`, the default view file will be set to `/app/View/Themed/Example/Posts/edit.ctp`.
Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html

5.I think the default extension of cakephp view files is `.ctp` but not `.ctl`. `.ctl` is used by Microsoft Visual Studio? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Looks like the only thing I was missing was the actual path should have been /user/logout not just /logout...  ARGH!

Comment: That still only got me the action, which was fine in THAT case.  In another issue later, I still needed to access a new view, so I still needed to resolve this.  I cound in the UserController, an array $this->Security->unlockedActions that listed all the views.  I added my page there.

Comment: You can set the view you read in your action with the method 3(by calling $this->render*('/sample/sample'). Basically you can put your view file anywhere you want and use the trick.

Comment: If you go with the default setting , cake read Views/<controller>/<action>.ctp .